# One background image for multiple divs

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to use 1 background image (1366x768) to use in several divs. But if i use :

```
.my_divs{
 background-image: url("image.jpg");
}
```

I only have the top left of the image on each divs. I would like to use the portion of the image based on the div position.
I can use transparency on the div and set the background to `body`.

It will work, but in my case i'm already using `background-image` for `body` with another image.

```
body{
 background-image: url("another_image.jpg");
}
```

Is there a way to maybe "see through" `body` and show the `html` background-image ? Or another css trick ?

**EDIT** : add simple example

```
<style>
.mydivs{
    padding:30px;
    margin:30px;
    background-image: url("2.jpg");
}
body{
    background-image: url("1.jpg");
}
#container{
}
</style>
<body>
    <div id='container'>
        <div class='mydivs'>1</div>
        <div class='mydivs'>2</div>
        <div class='mydivs'>3</div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: sorry, it's pretty unclear to me.

Comment: Add a single parent container for all relevant elements, and apply the background to it. For example: `<div class="my_divs_container"><div class="my_divs"></div><div class="my_divs"></div></div>`.

Comment: for example if `image.jpg` is a picture of a person. If i have 3 divs one after the other : I want the first one to show the head and the last one the feet. With `background-image` above i have the head on every divs. The tricky thing is i have space between each div and i want them to show another `background-image` based on `body` tag.

Comment: As Boaz just said, make a parent container with the background image.  Then make three child divs inside of that div.  For the child divs, set the background to transparent.

Comment: if i do that i cannot see the `background-image` from `body`. (space between my divs) Basically the container background is above body background.

Comment: i'm not sure about the best practice here.  But i rarely ever edit the body tag other than setting margins and font family.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the `background-attachment` property may do the trick for you.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#background-properties

If you use `background-attachment: fixed`, the background image is fixed with
respect to the viewport.  So, if you apply it to several elements, it is as if the background image is being viewed through "lenses" over the page.

If you page has a vertical scroll bar, then the background image will remain fixed as the content moves (this may not suit your design).

```css
.bgdeco {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/2000/700);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgdeco"></div>
<div class="bgdeco"></div>
<div class="bgdeco"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know how many divs you'll be spanning you can use `background-position` with a bit of simple math. Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ah2do0tp/).

Comment: i can manually change the `background-position` for every single divs but is this really the only way to achieve this ?

Comment: I honestly can't think of another approach to achieve that type of layout.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='divHead' class='mydivs'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='divTorso' class='mydivs'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='divLegs' class='mydivs'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
background-image:url('myPic.jpg');
}
.mydivs {
background-color:transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily a good solution -- but how about setting the borders of inner divs instead of the margins: the borders will be not transparent and cover the background image, the inner divs will be transparent and show the background image. You can set up the borders in vw and vh to make them responsive.

```
.inner-divs {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: rgb(255, 255, 255) solid 5vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set a transparent background to any HTML tag including body!
You can achieve your goal via multiple ways..

1. Add a background image to HTML tag and set `background: none;` to
   body and all leading tags
2. You can add a parent div to all the divs you want to set a single
   image background and than add `background-image` to parent div and
   set all chind div's `background: none;`

check out below example

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  }
body {
  background: red;
  }

#parent {
  background: url('http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/996335/251280085/stock-vector-abstract-polygonal-space-low-poly-dark-background-with-connecting-dots-and-lines-connection-251280085.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }
.child {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
 <div class="child">1</div>
 <div class="child">2</div>
 <div class="child">3</div>
 <div class="child">4</div>
 <div class="child">5</div>
 <div class="child">6</div>
 <div class="child">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `background-position: xpos ypos;` to adjust the position of the image.