# How to adjust a background image in one div to align with the next div?

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:
[image]

Where the blue triangle part of div 1 connects to div 2's and same goes for the triangle on the right, and for div 2 to connect with div 3 as well (maybe more).

I've found 2 possible solutions so far and tried them out which are:

1. Using 1 [full background image](https://imgur.com/RVz4LkN) where 3 background images of the 3 divs are combined into 1, then use `background-size: cover` and `background-attachment: fixed` (covered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100688/one-background-image-for-multiple-divs))
   Problem using this method: Vertical scrolling will ruin the content layout, e.g. text and images doesn't fit the current background image that I'm in/looking at.
2. Is to use `background-position` like `background-position: 50% 0px` for [div 1's background image](https://imgur.com/TLqBEiO) and `background-position: 50% -1200px` for [div 2's background image](https://imgur.com/WxKmf9K).
   Problem using this method: I would need to adjust for all kinds of screen sizes as the alignment between 2 divs goes away when I tried using different screen sizes.

Updated: Here's my current [code](https://jsfiddle.net/j0e5u7kn/).

I'm trying to look for better suggestions to achieve that effect and would appreciate it if anyone can lend me a hand here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But where is your code?

Comment: Just added it @FuriousMountain

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first solution you proposed, and if I have understood your requirements, it is possible to achieve the result by utilizing the background CSS rule property. Specifically, you need to set the `background-size` to the value `cover` and the `background-attachment` to the value `fixed`, as you already have.

The following link is to an example that displays the output you described: https://jsfiddle.net/v60y7beL/.

**The HTML that produces such an output can be found below:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/RVz4LkN.png'); /* The image URL you provided */
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            color: red;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .example-content {
            padding: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="example-content">
        <h1>Your Content Goes Here</h1>
        <p>Testing content for overflow behavior</p>
        <p>Testing content for overflow behavior</p>
        <p>Testing content for overflow behavior</p>
        <p>Testing content for overflow behavior</p>
        <p>Testing content for overflow behavior</p>
        <p>Testing content for overflow behavior</p>
        <p>Testing content for overflow behavior</p>
        <p>Testing content for overflow behavior</p>
        <p>Testing content for overflow behavior</p>
        <p>Testing content for overflow behavior</p>
        <p>Testing content for overflow behavior</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If this is not what you are looking for, kindly update your post.

Comment: Okay, this is what I've tried too but my concern is that vertical scrolling will ruin the content layout, e.g. text and images doesn't fit the current background image that I'm in/looking at.
I've also updated my post.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, it has no reason to mess with your layout, since it is a static background that will stay fixed as you scroll. You can try adding various elements of different sizes of your choice and see how it behaves. I believe it to be simpler to have only one image as a background. If the colors are of concern you can always create your own. Try flooding it with elements, and see what happens.

Comment: Okay I've tried doing this but I realized the background-image that I wanted is longer than what I've posted here (more than 2 big divs length), so essentially what I want to achieve is like I'm scrolling down a normal website with different backgrounds at different divs but the background will change instead of being fixed.

Comment: You could build your own image with as many different images put together as you like, and then have that background be repeated. The relevant CSS rule is: `background-repeat: repeat;`. When the initial background image you uploaded ends, it will be repeated for however long you scroll because of content. If you want to have different DIV elements depending on your content, you will have to manually implement your custom images in a similar manner to the one fashioned in your code.